# Error : Can't find variable: appName in react-native and Android

Tags: react-native

I am trying to run a react-native app on my android device, But I am getting an error like :

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: appName
```

[image]

OS:Ubuntu 18.04

Please anyone can help on this?

Comment: can you show me your code ?

Comment: The code works very well, here's the link on expo :
https://snack.expo.io/@waelj/948de7

Comment: On which page you have declare the variable appName ??

Comment: can you show your index.js, and does your app work on simulator?